# (JAVA) Post http request to Binance exchange errror

Tags: java, post

I am now working on GET current price of crypto currency from Binance.

I refer this API-DOCS(https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md), "symbol order book ticker"

however, my code shows some error response as follows

```
'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'

<html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html>
```

my codes are as shown below

```
public static void bid_ask () throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String queryArgs = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/bookTicker";
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(queryArgs);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));

}
```

Comment: The use of the name queryArgs is misleading, you’re passing a URL in string form that has no query arguments defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API’s documentation that you linked, that URL only supports GET requests, but you’re making a POST request.